# 500 Server Error - ImportError: No module named ssl

Tags: python, ssl, importerror

I've been using Google App Engine, and I've been having a lot of trouble with deploying my app. I've connected my source repository from Github on Google Cloud Platform, and I'm using Windows and Python 3.7 for this, for reference.

I've tried looking for similar issues to mine and trying out different solutions, as well as trying the GAE documentation to deploy my app, but I still end up getting "500 Server Error" instead and my page tells me "Error: Server Error". When I check Error Reporting, the error says "ImportError: No module named ssl", but I don't know how to deal with that.

As such, I wanted to know what could be causing this, be it still something in my code, or could it be related to my directory? Any response would be much appreciated.

The following is my "main.py" code:

```
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os
from webapp2_extras import sessions

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self):
        # Get a session store for this request.
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

        try:
            # Dispatch the request.
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        finally:
            # Save all sessions.
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        # Returns a session using the default cookie key.
        return self.session_store.get_session()

jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)

class MainPage(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        main_template = jinja_env.get_template('templates/index.html')
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')

        name = self.request.get("name")    # name
        self.session['name'] = name

        self.response.write(main_template.render(name=name))

    def post(self):
        main_template = jinja_env.get_template('templates/index.html')
        self.response.write('Inputted text: ' % self.request.get('name'))

        name = self.request.get("name")    # Category
        self.session['name'] = name

        self.response.write(main_template.render(name=name))

config = {}
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {
    'secret_key': 'my-super-secret-key',
}

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage)
], config=config,
   debug=True)
```

And this is my "app.yaml" code:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting brackets around `latest` in your definition for `app.yaml`

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: "latest"
- name: ssl
  version: "latest"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! Unfortunately, I've tried that and it didn't work.